# Jekyll error on serve or build

Tags: jekyll

Can anyone assist with the following Jekyll error?

```
H:\jekyll\styleguide>jekyll build
Configuration file: H:/jekyll/styleguide/_config.yml
            Source: H:/jekyll/styleguide
       Destination: H:/jekyll/styleguide/_site
      Generating... enter code here
Error reading file H:/jekyll/styleguide/_android/1_lorem-ipsum.md: undefined met
hod `fetch' for "output:true":String
  Liquid Exception: undefined method `fetch' for "output:true":String in _layout
s/default.html
jekyll 2.4.0 | Error:  undefined method `fetch' for "output:true":String
```

Code of 1_lorem_ipsum.md attached below:

```
---
layout: default
title: Lorem Ipsum
---

Lorem Ipsum
==========


Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
```

Comment: Show us some code (eg: 1_lorem-ipsum.md)

Comment: Added the code above

Comment: Not problem in this post. Can you push to a github repository, it will be easier to debug ?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed. There was a missing space in the config.yml file :)